# BluetoothServerSocket - Why use a temporary variable?

Tags: java, android, final

What is the use of assigning temporary variables in the following code? What difference does it make if I use mmServerSocket directly. Why do I have initialise mmServerSocket as a final?

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

public AcceptThread() {
    // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket,
    // because mmServerSocket is final
    BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
    try {
        // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
        tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
    mmServerSocket = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ensures that `mmServerSocket` is definitely assigned a value exactly once, a requirement that the constructor must satisfy for `final` instance variables. It might seem like one could avoid a temporary variable as follows:

```
try {
    mmServerSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
} catch (IOException e) {
    mmServerSocket = null;
}
```

However, the compiler will complain that at the assignment in the `catch` block, `mmServerSocket` may have already been assigned. I don't know why the compiler can't figure out in this case that there is no possibility of an exception once the method call returns, but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

It's just poor code.

- The `mmServerSocket` variable doesn't need to be final.
- The constructor should just attempt to construct the `BluetoothServerSocket` directly without all this fuss.
- It should also throw `IOException` if it fails, instead of failing silently and eating the exception and leaving a null variable lying around to cause NPEs later on.

Comment: But perhaps the rest of the code will work just fine with a `null` value for `mmServerSocket` when an `IOException` is thrown.

Comment: @TedHopp Or perhaps not. If an exception is thrown, the `AcceptThread` doesn't even get constructed, so the rest of the code doesn't have to be specially coded, and subjected to 'perhaps' speculations.

Comment: My point is that an `AcceptThread` might still be useful (perhaps using fall-back functionality that doesn't involve BlueTooth) even if an exception is thrown. We just don't know. If you insist that the API must be redefined to propagate the exception, you are precluding the possibility of constructing an `AcceptThread` when there's an exception.